# Extra large background modal using small Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm having an issue with a Bootstrap modal where if I change the size to small, there is a lingering backdrop modal behind it that is still large.

[image]

In the Elements window I can remove the class="modal-content" right before uib-modal-transclude and the modal behind disappears. However I am trying to apply this change in my code and can't get it to work.

First off, this code seems to be coming from `uib/template/modal/window.html` or https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/modal/window.html

I am using ui_bootstrap/1.1.2

I tried to overwrite the template using windowtemplateurl and making the new template have:

```
  <div modal-render="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope in"
     uib-modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}"
     uib-modal-window="modal-window" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate" modal-animation="true"
     style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
        <div uib-modal-transclude=""><!--

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="Cancel()"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title ng-binding" id="notfound"> Not Found</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="Cancel()">Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This didn't work. It doesn't seem like changing windowTemplateUrl changed anything at all... I also tried adding css to modal-content, however this screws up other modals on this page.

Am I on the right track? Where is this error coming from? What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: You used the "modal-xl" class on the modal dialog though. Change that to "modal-sm".

Comment: @RachelS Yes I saw that as well, but again that is in the window.html code, and my override isn't working.

Comment: @RachelS I changed modal-xl to modal-sm as well as size="sm" right above it and still have a modal in the background, though it is smaller. The surrounding modal is 300x184 whereas my modal is 300x122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this error, here is what I did to fix it.

I did find a declaration for the size of the modal to be "`xl`" in my code. Changed that to "`sm`" and there was still a wrapper around my modal that was 300x184 whereas my modal was 300x122.

I took out the `class="modal-dialog"` div wrapper and the second modal disappeared.